# How to avoid showing loading state after the initial load in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

In the example below when the data is fetched the "Loading..." text will be shown.

Is there a way to avoid showing this loading state after the initial load?

So when you click on "Update" button, instead of showing "Loading..." it would keep the existing data with the `.loading` class and when the new data is loaded updates it with the new data?

[playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/5f349fa82fc1497f9a88008fe3186136?version=3.38.2)

```svelte
<button on:click={() => namep = getName()}>Update</button>
{#await namep}
  <div>Waiting...</div>
{:then name}
  <div>Hello {name}!</div>
{/await}

<script>
  let i = 0
  function getName() {
    return new Promise((set) => setTimeout(() => set(`Alex ${i++}`), 1000))  
  }
  
  let namep = getName()
</script>

<style>
  .loading { color: #ccc; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to just use the reactive variable `lastData` that will be updated in the Promise of the `getName` function. Then in your template just check if `lastData` is defined to show the name. You will need to make the first `getName` call in an `onMount` callback:

```html
<button on:click={getName}>Update</button>
{#if lastData}
    <div>Hello {lastData}!</div>
{:else}
    <div>Waiting...</div>
{/if}

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let i = 0
    let lastData = undefined

    function getName() {
        new Promise(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                lastData = `Alex ${i++}`
            }, 1000)
        })  
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        getName()
    })
</script>

<style>
    .loading { color: #ccc; }
</style>
```

See the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d0a9d6fac6043f1988f8eae875017cc?version=3.38.2).

Comment: Thanks! One question, why do you need `onMount`? The script works without it, if you just call `getName()` directly in the script.

Comment: It makes you sure that all the component are loaded properly and ready to work like it should. An example is that the `Waiting... ` node is not rendered yet so `getName` is called without direcly showing the loading animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could fake it by setting each call in a separate variable and checking for that variable in the first part of the `#await` block and showing the old data if it exists instead of the loading message. Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2869eec9a9e142ba9a592d76c7059e3c?version=3.38.2) for it.

```html
<button on:click={() => namep = getName()}>Update</button>
{#await namep}
    {#if oldData}
        <div class="loading">Hello {oldData}!</div>
    {:else}
        <div class="loading">Waiting...</div>
    {/if}
{:then name}
  <div>Hello {name}!</div>
{/await}

<script>
  let i = 0
  let oldData
    
  function getName() {
    return new Promise((set) => setTimeout(() => set(`Alex ${i++}`), 1000)).then(a => {
            return oldData = a
        })
    }
  
  let namep = getName()
</script>

<style>
  .loading { color: #ccc; }
</style>
```